# Spring, eclipselink, compass integration

Tags: spring, transactions, integration, eclipselink, compass-geolocation

I went through several articles and configured the following, but i can see some problems with transaction management. Please let me know whether i'm using compass correctly in the below configurations:

in Spring-config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
id="transactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
<property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.compass.spring.support.CompassContextBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="compass" class="org.compass.spring.LocalCompassBean">
<property name="classMappings">
<list>
<value>......</value>
<value>......</value>
<value>......</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="compassSettings">
<props>
<prop key="compass.engine.connection">file:///usr/local/lucene</prop>
<prop key="compass.transaction.factory">
org.compass.spring.transaction.SpringSyncTransactionFactory
</prop>
</props>
</property>
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

in compass code:

```
private CompassSession session;

@CompassContext
protected void setCompassSession(CompassSession session) {
this.session = session;

}

public void index(Coupon coupon) throws AppException{
try {
session.save(coupon);
} catch (CompassException exception) {
logger.debug("Error in coupon indexing: "+ exception.getMessage());
}
}
```

in Service Layer:

```
@Transactional
public void saveCoupon(Coupon coupon) throws AppException{
Coupon savedCoupon = dbCouponDAO.saveCoupon(coupon); // saves to db through eclipselink
nonDbCouponDAO.index(savedCoupon); // indexes in compass
}
```

As per my understanding, transaction manager configured to eclipselink in spring can be used as compass transaction manager too, and both eclipselink and compass operations can be used in a single unit as i have mentioned in service layer.

Please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this,

```
<!-- Search Manager using Comass abstractions. -->
<bean class="org.compass.spring.support.CompassContextBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="compass" class="org.compass.spring.LocalCompassBean">
    <property name="compassSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="compass.engine.connection">file://${user.home}/indexes</prop>
            <prop key="compass.transaction.factory">org.compass.spring.transaction.SpringSyncTransactionFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="classMappings">
        <list>
            <value>MyEntity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref local="transactionManager" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jpaGpsDevice" class="org.compass.gps.device.jpa.JpaGpsDevice">
    <property name="name">
        <value>jpaDevice</value>
    </property>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory">
        <ref local="entityManagerFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="nativeExtractor">
        <bean class="org.compass.gps.device.jpa.extractor.SpringNativeJpaExtractor" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="compassGps" class="org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="compass">
        <ref bean="compass" />
    </property>
    <property name="gpsDevices">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jpaGpsDevice" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- COMPASS END -->
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: With my configuration I was able to make indexes transparently without writing any additional code.